# google geocharts make clickable countries and change color of selected countries

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization, google-geocoding-api

I am using geochart from google for my website, but I want the countries to be clickable. When I click one country it's colour to be changed and stay selected while selecting other countries.

I need to make geochart like in following url:

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

JS

```
 google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages':['geochart'],
    // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
    // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
    'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700],
      ['India', 700]
    ]);

    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ztn2a3m8/)

[Selecting countries on a map](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/selecting-countries-map/)

Comment: I am using code from  https://jsfiddle.net/ztn2a3m8/1/  for geochart

Comment: Why don't you use the code from that page?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with GeoChart.